# Stopping list selection?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Imagine that I have an order list of tuples:

```
s = [(0,-1), (1,0), (2,-1), (3,0), (4,0), (5,-1), (6,0), (7,-1)]
```

Given a parameter `X`, I want to select all the tuples that have a first element equal or greater than `X` up to but not including the first tuple that has -1 as the second element.

For example, if `X = 3`, I want to select the list `[(3,0), (4,0)]`

One idea I had is: 
Get the cut-off key with

```
E = min (x [0] for x in s if (x [0] >= X) and (x [1] == -1) )
```

Then select elements with keys between the `X` and `E`:

```
R = [x for x in s if X <= x [0] < E]
```

That gives me what I want in R, but it seems really inefficient, involving two table scans.  I could do it in a for loop, discarding tuples with keys too small, and *break* when I hit the first blocking tuple.  But for runs like a dog compared to list selection.

Is there a super-efficient, python-esque (2.7) way of doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can simply filter the tuples from the list as a generator expression and then you can stop taking the values from the generator expression when you get the first tuple whose second element is `-1`, like this

```
>>> s = [(0,-1), (1,0), (2,-1), (3,0), (4,0), (5,-1), (6,0), (7,-1)]
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> X = 3
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] != -1, (item for item in s if item[0] >= X)))
[(3, 0), (4, 0)]
```

Here, the generator expression, `(item for item in s if item[0] >= X)` will give values one-by-one, on demand, (they are not generated all at once, so we save memory here) which are greater than or equal to `X`.

Then, we take values from that generator expression, only till we find a tuple whose second element is not equal to `-1`, with [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: your answer elegantly satisfies my every concern.  I weep with joy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly hacky to implement `takewhile` as part of a generator expression:

```
def stop(): raise StopIteration

result = (
    stop() if item[1] == -1 else
    item
    for item in s
    if item[0] >= X
)
```

Or with different phrasing:

```
def until(cond):
    if cond: raise StopIteration
    return True

result = (
    item for item in s
    if item[0] >= X
    and until(item[1] == -1)
)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, similar approach won't work in list comprehensions, because the `if` clause is outside the `StopIteration` handling by the comprehension/generator internal code, so the exception propagates. (With generators it does too, but it gets handled naturally by the code that *uses* the generator). This comment is for potential benefit of those who would try to apply this technique to a comprehension and get surprized, like I was. :)